# How do you define the implementation of function nested class outside of the function?

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I have code like this:

```
class A {
  void foo() {
    class B {
      void bar() { std::cout << "Bar!" << endl; }
    };
    B b;
  }
};
```

However I would like to implement the struct `B` outside of the function scope. If this was just a nested class in `A` I could do something like:

```
class X {
  void foo();
  class Y;
}
class X::Y {
  void bar() { std::cout << "Bar!" << endl; }
}
```

But I cannot work out if it is possible to do a similar thing for class `B`. The compiler tells me that the type of that class is `A::foo::B` but if I attempt to define that class I am told that `foo` is not a member of `A`:

*An attempt:*

```
class A {
  void foo();
};

class A::foo::C {
  void bar() { std::cout << "Bar!" << std::endl; }
};

void A::foo()  {
  class C;
  C c;
  c.bar();
}
```

Errors:

```
test.cpp(15) : error C3083: 'foo': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
test.cpp(15) : error C2039: 'C' : is not a member of 'A'
    test.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'A'
test.cpp(19) : error C2079: 'c' uses undefined class 'A::foo::C'
```

Comment: It's not possible, because in the first example the class `B` is not really nested inside the `A` class. It's local inside the `A::foo` function so the whole definition have to be inside that function.

Comment: This isn't possible because `B` is local to the method `bar`.

Comment: Put `B` in an unnamed namespace at file scope.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But `Y` is local to the class `X` and I can do it there. Is there some fundamental difference between class and function scopes?

Comment: @Jarod42 But then people outside the scope of `A::foo` can refer to it, that is a different thing to what I want.

Comment: @sji Yes, the fundamental difference is that `B` is local for the function scope.

Comment: @sji: I agree that more functions can access it, but as it is limited to the file scope, you should have good control on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. The name `C` is not visible outside of the scope of the function `foo`. And unlike for classes, there is now way to reach into a function scope from outside that function.

Notice that `A` is totally irrelevant in your example. If `foo` was a namespace-scope function, the result would be exactly the same.

If you want a function-local class, you have to implement it entirely inside that function.